# Refresh a subview?

Tags: ios, ios5, view, subview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` with four segments. Some of the `subviews` are present in both the segments. Now on click of a segment i want all the subviews to be refreshed to their default state.

To make it more clear, if I have a button being with default title `FootyApps`, shared between two segments, and if I set the button title in one segment as `Hello`, then on click 0f second segment I want the button to display `FootyApps` and not "Hello".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set it back manually. There is no "initial" state saved for your views. No way to go back automatically.

Comment: so i need to set all the values of subviews again? wont that affect the performance?

Comment: @footyapps27 Do you have problems with performance? Updating labels won't affect it